# Keeping a model in camera view at all times - Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I set up the appropriate size of the Frustum such that a moving camera needs to keep an object (such as the 3D model) completely in a scene at all times that it must not get so close that part of that object is cut off.

The model doesn't move.

Comment: You could use your Camera > Clipping Planes > Near value (e.g. the default 0.3f) plus a minor security padding (e.g. 0.01f) as radius for an isTrigger SphereCollider, which `OnTriggerEnter` stops moving towards the given target object. Note it might be useful if you posted your current relevant camera movement code.

Answer (score 0):

If camera is always pointed to your object and the object is in the center of screen you can solve this problem easily here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FrustumSizeAtDistance.html
.But in general, this class would do the task. First, you need to consider a virtual sphere around your object which includes your object entirely and this code avoids the object get out of the screen.

```
public class PutObjectAlwaysInScreen : MonoBehaviour {

//Object Transform that should be in the screen
public Transform Target;
//Considering a sphere around your object according to its size
public float Radius;

void check()
{
    //Finding a frustum plate that include object position point
    //the vector from camera to frustum plate
    Vector3 Vcenter = Camera.main.transform.forward;
    //Vector between camera and object
    Vector3 VcameraToObject = Target.position - Camera.main.transform.position;
    //The angle between center of frustum and object postion
    float CosTeta = Vector3.Dot(Vcenter,VcameraToObject)/(Vcenter.magnitude * VcameraToObject.magnitude);
    //distance between camera and frustum
    float distance = VcameraToObject.magnitude * CosTeta;
    //Center of frustum plate
    Vector3 Fcenter = Camera.main.transform.position + distance * (Vcenter/Vcenter.magnitude);
    //Vector between center of frustum and object
    Vector3 FrustumToObject = Target.position - Fcenter;
    //Width And Height of the distance between center of frustum and object in the screen
    float W = Vector3.Dot(FrustumToObject,Camera.main.transform.right);
    float H = Vector3.Dot(FrustumToObject,Camera.main.transform.up);
    //frustum Width and Height
    float frustumHeight = 2.0f * distance * Mathf.Tan(Camera.main.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float frustumWidth = frustumHeight * Camera.main.aspect;
    //Check if the object is out of the screen
    if( ((Mathf.Abs(W)+Radius)>frustumWidth) || ((Mathf.Abs(H)+Radius)>frustumHeight) )
    {
        // Do Something
        // You Can Avoid Camera from getting closer to the Object

        //or With the below formulae adjust the fieldOfView
        if((Mathf.Abs(W)+Radius)>frustumHeight)
            Camera.main.fieldOfView = 2.0f * Mathf.Atan((Mathf.Abs(H)+Radius) * 0.5f / distance) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        if((Mathf.Abs(W)+Radius)>frustumWidth)
            Camera.main.fieldOfView = 2.0f * Mathf.Atan(((Mathf.Abs(W)+Radius)/Camera.main.aspect) * 0.5f / distance) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    }


}

    void Update() {
    check();
    }
}
```